# PHP - Multiple Select queries based on If else conditions

Tags: php, select, mysqli

I need help with Multiple Select queries based on If else conditions. I've multiple tables and I want to work queries like this.

1. Search in table1, if found then return the result.
2. If not found then search in table2.
3. If word not found in both table1 and table2 then check in table3 and after that check in table4

I'm using below codes.

```
        <?php
    // 1. Create a database connection
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "us");

    /* check connection */
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    $term = strip_tags(substr($_POST['searchit'],0, 100));
    $term = $mysqli->real_escape_string($term); 

    if($term=="") {
    echo "Enter Something to search";
        exit();
    }


    if(
        $result = $mysqli->query("Select * from table1 where word like '{$term}%'
                        UNION
                        Select * from table2 where word like '{$term}%'")){

       $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
             {
        echo "Stem : {$row['word']} <br>";
    }
    }

        else {
             $result = $mysqli->query("Select * from table3 where words like '{$term}%'");

                    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
             {
        echo "words: {$row['words']} <br>";
    }
    }
}
}

    else{
     echo "No matches found!";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to strip `$row['prefix']` from `$term`?

Comment: Could you provide examples of table 3, table 2, table 1, input, and intended result so that we can tell exactly what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
str_replace($row['prefix'],'',$term );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. On which specific position I need to apply this because my table3 query is already not displaying any result.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 mb_internal_encoding( 'UTF-8');



   $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "us");
   if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
   }

   $mysqli->query("SET WORDS 'utf8'");
   $mysqli->query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8'); 


   $term = strip_tags(substr($_POST['searchit'],0, 100));
   $term = $mysqli->real_escape_string($term); 

   if($term=="") {
     echo "Enter Something to search";
     exit();
   }




   termcheck($term, $mysqli);             
   function termcheck($term, $mysqli){
     $qry="Select * from table1 where word ='$term' UNION Select * from table2 where word = '$term'";
     if($result = $mysqli->query($qry)){
        //echo "inside sql table1";
       $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
         if($num_rows > 0) {
            //echo "inside table1";
           while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
             {
               echo "Stem : ".$row['term']."<br>";
             }
             exit();
         }
      }else {

           $qry1="Select * from table3";
           $result = $mysqli->query($qry1);
           $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
           if($num_rows > 0) {

             while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "inside while";
               if($table4=mb_strrichr($term,$row['prefix'])){
                echo "inside if";
                  $sterm=str_replace($row['prefix'],'',$term);
                  $postfix=$row['prefix'];
                echo "inside : ".$sterm;
                }
             }
           }else{echo "Error : Table3 doesn't exist";}
         }

         if(!empty($sterm)){
           $qry3="Select * from table4";
           $result3 = $mysqli->query($qry3);
           $num_rows = $result3->num_rows;
           if($num_rows > 0) {
             while($row = $result3->fetch_assoc()){
               if(mb_strrichr($sterm,$row['postfix'])){
                  $ssterm=str_replace($row['postfix'],'',$sterm);
                  $prefix=$row['postfix'];
                  echo "prefix : ".$prefix;
                  echo "<br>";
                  echo "postfix : ".$postfix;
                  echo "<br>";
                  echo "sterm : ".$ssterm;
                } 
             }exit();
           }else{echo "Error : Table3 doesn't exist";}
         }else{
           $qry3="Select * from table4";
           $result3 = $mysqli->query($qry3);
           $num_rows = $result3->num_rows;
           if($num_rows > 0) {
             while($row = $result3->fetch_assoc()){
               if(mb_strrichr($term,$row['postfix'])){
                  $prefix=$row['postfix'];
                  $sterm=str_replace( $row['postfix'],'',$term);
                  echo "prefix : ".$prefix;
                  echo "<br>";
                  echo "sterm : ".$sterm;
               }
             }exit();
           } else{echo "Error : Table3 doesn't exist";}          
         }
       }


  ?>
```

Comment: I can't see my previous comments here. Did you get my previous comment?

Comment: sorry little busy when do want to finish it?

Comment: I want to finish it as soon as possible. When you get some extra time then please help. Thanks a lot for all your help.

Comment: there is no defined functions for your language that's the problem

Comment: So what's  the solution?

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're great

Comment: tell me something unique about your words. how somebody could identify that these are the words in a sentence?

Comment: what is tbe I don't understand

Comment: Edited,  Check above comments again

Comment: Sorry i am not getting you?

Comment: In your language how do you identify the words in a sentence?

Comment: no what I am asking is different..... If you input a sentence I first need to take the last word from the sentence. so first I need to know the words in a sentence in urdu . forget about tables for now. tell me how to find the words in your language by looking at it.

Comment: user can input any word or the words you specify? لاہوری ,->explain with this.

Comment: post table1 value tabl2 value table3 value and table4 value from your table name the tables as postfix prefix sterm

Comment: table3 is for postfix and table 4 prefix?

Comment: Should i need to change database table3 with table4? If i did something wrong?

Comment: that's because I have given the input inside the script. Now I removed it try now. how come u always online. what time is it there now?

Comment: was you input is this "لاہوری" ?

Comment: For the word لاہوری: I added ہور in table2, لا in table3, ی in table4

Comment: how come you find correct result? I don't understand because my output is different.

Comment: no idea I am getting the correct result just update check it.

Comment: I have actually added the input inside the query uncomment it you will come to know..